# Кастомный фон с кастомной анимацией. Непрерывная анимация по дуге между рандомными точками

Tags: android, android-animation

Всем привет. Требуется сделать анимацию фона с бесконечным смещением по рандомным X и Y координатам. В качестве фона - сетка с повторяющимися `View`. Я решил что размеры полотна будут равны утроенным сторонам экрана.

Получилось следующее:

```
class FlyingBackgroundView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

    companion object {
        private const val SMOOTH_ANIMATION_DURATION = 10000L
        private const val SCREEN_WIDTH_FACTOR = 3
        private const val SCREEN_HEIGHT_FACTOR = 3
        private const val ICON_SIZE_DP = 60
    }

    private val iconSubstrateColor = Color.parseColor("#eeeeee")
    private val columnContainer: LinearLayout

    private val icons = ArrayList<ImageView>()

    init {
        val iconSize = dpToPx(ICON_SIZE_DP)
        val iconSubstrateSize = iconSize * 1.5f
        val itemSize = iconSubstrateSize * 1.3f

        val screenMetrics = createDisplayMetrics(context as Activity)
        val screenWidth = screenMetrics.widthPixels
        val screenHeight = screenMetrics.heightPixels

        var columnCount = (screenWidth / itemSize).toInt() * SCREEN_WIDTH_FACTOR
        val itemCount = (screenHeight / itemSize).toInt() * SCREEN_HEIGHT_FACTOR

        if (columnCount.isEven()) columnCount++

        val canvasWidth = columnCount * itemSize.toInt()
        val canvasHeight = itemCount * itemSize.toInt()

        columnContainer = LinearLayout(context)
        columnContainer.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
        columnContainer.clipChildren = false

        for (column in 0 until columnCount) {
            val columnLayout = LinearLayout(context)
            columnLayout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(itemSize.toInt(),
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            columnLayout.clipChildren = false
            columnLayout.orientation = VERTICAL
            columnLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER

            val countOfItems = if (column.isEven()) itemCount else itemCount - 1
            for (item in 0 until countOfItems) {
                val itemLayout = LinearLayout(context)
                itemLayout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(itemSize.toInt(), itemSize.toInt())
                itemLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER

                val substrateLayout = LinearLayout(context)
                substrateLayout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(iconSubstrateSize.toInt(),
                        iconSubstrateSize.toInt())
                substrateLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                val circleBackground = GradientDrawable()
                circleBackground.shape = GradientDrawable.OVAL
                circleBackground.setColor(iconSubstrateColor)
                substrateLayout.placeBackgroundDrawable(circleBackground)

                val iconView = ImageView(context)
                iconView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(iconSize, iconSize)
                icons.add(iconView)

                substrateLayout.addView(iconView)
                itemLayout.addView(substrateLayout)
                columnLayout.addView(itemLayout)
            }
            columnContainer.addView(columnLayout)
        }

        val centerX = canvasWidth / SCREEN_WIDTH_FACTOR
        val centerY = canvasHeight / SCREEN_HEIGHT_FACTOR
        columnContainer.x = -centerX.toFloat()
        columnContainer.y = -centerY.toFloat()
        addView(columnContainer)

        val maxX = canvasWidth / SCREEN_WIDTH_FACTOR * (SCREEN_WIDTH_FACTOR - 1)
        val maxY = canvasHeight / SCREEN_HEIGHT_FACTOR * (SCREEN_HEIGHT_FACTOR - 1)

        (object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                val randomX = Random().nextInt(maxX)
                val randomY = Random().nextInt(maxY)

                ViewCompat.animate(columnContainer)
                        .x(-randomX.toFloat())
                        .y(-randomY.toFloat())
                        .setDuration(SMOOTH_ANIMATION_DURATION)
                        .withEndAction(this)
                        .start()
            }
        }).run()
    }

    fun setIcon(@DrawableRes iconResId: Int) {
        icons.forEach { icon ->
            ViewCompat.animate(icon)
                    .scaleX(0f)
                    .scaleY(0f)
                    .alpha(0f)
                    .setDuration(1000).withEndAction {
                        icon.setImageResource(iconResId)
                        ViewCompat.animate(icon)
                                .scaleX(1f)
                                .scaleY(1f)
                                .alpha(1f)
                                .setDuration(1000)
                                .start()
                    }.start()
        }
    }

}
```

**Kotlin extensions**

```
fun View.placeBackgroundDrawable(drawable: Drawable) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        background = drawable
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        setBackgroundDrawable(drawable)
    }
}

fun Int.isEven() = rem(2) == 0
```

**Kotlin global methods**

```
fun createDisplayMetrics(activity: Activity): DisplayMetrics {
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
    return metrics
}

fun dpToPx(dp: Int) = (dp * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

Пожалуйста, уделите время, запустите у себя. Вот что меня не устраивает до конца:

- Анимация останавливается перед началом следующей. Как сделать, чтобы она шла непрерывно, то есть по окончании сразу начиналось следующее перемещение на другие координаты, без остановок и замедлений? Я же вроде не использую интерполяторы.
- Как сделать чтобы анимация шла по дуге, а не прямо? Допустим, текущие координаты - 0, 0. Начинается анимация к точке 70, 60. Это можно представить как прямоугольник. Так вот, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы анимация шла не линейно по диагонали прямоугольника, а по дуге (сквозь любой из двух треугольников - это не важно). Но я не знаю через что и как высчитывать углы и т.д

**UPD**

Написал мини-пример. Здесь квадрат перемещается между рандомными точками в пределах одного экрана. Конкретно в этом примере необходимо указать тему `NoActionBar.Fullscreen`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final long FLY_DURATION = 10000L;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        final View view = new View(this);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        int viewSize = dpToPx(50);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(viewSize, viewSize));
        rootView.addView(view);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        final int maxX = metrics.widthPixels - viewSize;
        final int maxY = metrics.heightPixels - viewSize;

        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int randomX = new Random().nextInt(maxX);
                int randomY = new Random().nextInt(maxY);

                view.animate()
                    .x(randomX)
                    .y(randomY)
                    .setDuration(FLY_DURATION)
                    .withEndAction(this)
                    .start();
            }
        }.run();
    }

    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
}
```

Comment: Еще не запускал у себя, но вы точно не хотите использовать Animator-классы?

Comment: @ОлегКотенко, скорее всего аниматоры нужны будут.. Я сейчас немного код оптимизирую

Comment: @ОлегКотенко, обновил вопрос :)

Comment: Как то у вас все сложно сделано. Посмотрел пример в youtube, подумал что с изображением втрое больше по осям чем экран это расточительно(а может и нет), и вот можно ж реализовать все с помощью трех view-одна основная(в размер экрана) и две -это их обрезки по обоим осям, которые подстраиваются в места,где при движении основной вью остаются пустые области. Дадада,может рассчеты всего этого расточительнее гиганского изображения,я хз,просто предлагаю. А так, вот схожая с вашей цель - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894384/android-move-background-continuously-with-animation

Comment: p.s. VA рулит! ObjectAnimator в некоторых случаях не обеспечит плавную смену одной анимации view  на другую,этой же view. Старый OA не отдаст вьюху,пока не закончит анимацию(по наблюдениям,отдаст,но выглядеть будет ужасно). Столько возможных реализаций анимации,и все какие то...вспомнить хотя бы,не помню точно,вроде в animation, нельзя прикоснутся к view(non-clickable), пока она не анимирована до конца. VA тоже не сахар, скоро юбилей моего вопроса о нем(300 просмотров(ru+en))(рекламка)

Comment: @Олег Котенко, мой мозг очень страдал 2 дня :) я это-то еле смог сделать)

Comment: Это не моя цель) Там горизонтальное смещение, у меня же двунаправленное, ездиющее по полотну без перестановки вьюх. Вопрос вообще в анимации дуги.. Кучу способов нахожу но не пойму никак

Comment: Дык что мешает добавить Y ось?) Блин, да VA вообще будто именно для твоей задачи создавался,  там в одном его (вроде update-)listener-e можно две translation выполнять - х и у,а дуга можно,к примеру, расчитать с [Graphics.drawArc()](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/GraphicsdrawArcintxintyintwidthintheightintstartAngleintarcAngle.html) (или взять часть его алгоритма,а не "рассчитать с").

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172969/translate-curve-path-scale-animation-android

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83561/discussion-between-flippy-and--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел `ArcTranslateAnimation` у кого-то на гисте. Вроде получилось именно то, что я хочу! Оставлю это тут, может кому-то пригодится:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final long FLY_DURATION = 900L;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        final View view = new View(this);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        final int viewSize = dpToPx(50);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(viewSize, viewSize));
        rootView.addView(view);

        final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        final int maxX = metrics.widthPixels - viewSize;
        final int maxY = metrics.heightPixels - viewSize;

        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final int randomX = new Random().nextInt(maxX);
                final int randomY = new Random().nextInt(maxY);

                ArcTranslateAnimation anim = new ArcTranslateAnimation(view, randomX, randomY);
                anim.setDuration(FLY_DURATION);
                anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation p1)
                        {}

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation p1) {
                            run();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation p1)
                        {}
                });
                view.startAnimation(anim);
                float[] zooms = new float[] {1.1f, 1.2f, 0.8f, 0.9f, 1f};
                float zoom = zooms[new Random().nextInt(zooms.length)];
                view.animate().scaleX(zoom).scaleY(zoom).setDuration(FLY_DURATION).setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(4f)).start();
            }
        }.run();
    }

    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }

    public class ArcTranslateAnimation extends Animation {

        private float mFromXValue = 0.0f;
        private float mToXValue = 0.0f;

        private float mFromYValue = 0.0f;
        private float mToYValue = 0.0f;

        private float mFromXDelta;
        private float mToXDelta;
        private float mFromYDelta;
        private float mToYDelta;

        private PointF mStart;
        private PointF mControl;
        private PointF mEnd;

        private View mAnimatedView;

        public ArcTranslateAnimation(View animatedView, float toXValue, float toYValue) {
            mAnimatedView = animatedView;
            mFromXValue = animatedView.getX();
            mToXValue = toXValue;
            mFromYValue = animatedView.getY();
            mToYValue = toYValue;
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            float dx = calcBezier(interpolatedTime, mStart.x, mControl.x, mEnd.x);
            float dy = calcBezier(interpolatedTime, mStart.y, mControl.y, mEnd.y);
            mAnimatedView.setX(dx);
            mAnimatedView.setY(dy);
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
            super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
            mFromXDelta = resolveSize(ABSOLUTE, mFromXValue, width, parentWidth);
            mToXDelta = resolveSize(ABSOLUTE, mToXValue, width, parentWidth);
            mFromYDelta = resolveSize(ABSOLUTE, mFromYValue, height, parentHeight);
            mToYDelta = resolveSize(ABSOLUTE, mToYValue, height, parentHeight);

            mStart = new PointF(mFromXDelta, mFromYDelta);
            mEnd = new PointF(mToXDelta, mToYDelta);
            mControl = new PointF(mFromXDelta, mToYDelta); // How to choose the
        }

        private long calcBezier(float interpolatedTime, float p0, float p1, float p2) {
            return Math.round((Math.pow((1 - interpolatedTime), 2) * p0)
                              + (2 * (1 - interpolatedTime) * interpolatedTime * p1)
                              + (Math.pow(interpolatedTime, 2) * p2));
        }
    }
}
```

И конкретно по задаче:

```
class FlyingBackgroundView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

    companion object {
        private const val FLY_DURATION = 10000L
        private const val SCREEN_WIDTH_FACTOR = 3
        private const val SCREEN_HEIGHT_FACTOR = 3
        private const val ICON_SIZE_DP = 60
    }

    private val iconSubstrateColor = Color.parseColor("#eeeeee")
    private val columnContainer: LinearLayout

    private val icons = ArrayList<ImageView>()

    init {
        val iconSize = dpToPx(ICON_SIZE_DP)
        val iconSubstrateSize = iconSize * 1.5f
        val itemSize = iconSubstrateSize * 2f

        val screenMetrics = createDisplayMetrics(context as Activity)
        val screenWidth = screenMetrics.widthPixels
        val screenHeight = screenMetrics.heightPixels

        var columnCount = (screenWidth / itemSize).toInt() * SCREEN_WIDTH_FACTOR
        val itemCount = (screenHeight / itemSize).toInt() * SCREEN_HEIGHT_FACTOR

        if (columnCount.isEven()) columnCount++

        val canvasWidth = columnCount * itemSize.toInt()
        val canvasHeight = itemCount * itemSize.toInt()

        columnContainer = LinearLayout(context)
        columnContainer.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
        columnContainer.clipChildren = false

        for (column in 0 until columnCount) {
            val columnLayout = LinearLayout(context)
            columnLayout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(itemSize.toInt(),
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            columnLayout.clipChildren = false
            columnLayout.orientation = VERTICAL
            columnLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER

            val countOfItems = if (column.isEven()) itemCount else itemCount - 1
            for (item in 0 until countOfItems) {
                val itemLayout = LinearLayout(context)
                itemLayout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(itemSize.toInt(), itemSize.toInt())
                itemLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER

                val substrateLayout = LinearLayout(context)
                substrateLayout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(iconSubstrateSize.toInt(),
                        iconSubstrateSize.toInt())
                substrateLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                val circleBackground = GradientDrawable()
                circleBackground.shape = GradientDrawable.OVAL
                circleBackground.setColor(iconSubstrateColor)
                substrateLayout.placeBackgroundDrawable(circleBackground)

                val iconView = ImageView(context)
                iconView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(iconSize, iconSize)
                icons.add(iconView)

                substrateLayout.addView(iconView)
                itemLayout.addView(substrateLayout)
                columnLayout.addView(itemLayout)
            }
            columnContainer.addView(columnLayout)
        }


        addView(columnContainer)

        val centerX = canvasWidth / SCREEN_WIDTH_FACTOR
        val centerY = canvasHeight / SCREEN_HEIGHT_FACTOR
        columnContainer.x = -centerX.toFloat()
        columnContainer.y = -centerY.toFloat()

        val maxX = canvasWidth / SCREEN_WIDTH_FACTOR * (SCREEN_WIDTH_FACTOR - 1)
        val maxY = canvasHeight / SCREEN_HEIGHT_FACTOR * (SCREEN_HEIGHT_FACTOR - 1)

        (object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                val randomX = Random().nextInt(maxX).toFloat()
                val randomY = Random().nextInt(maxY).toFloat()

                val anim = ArcTranslateAnimation(columnContainer, -randomX, -randomY)
                anim.duration = FLY_DURATION
                anim.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
                anim.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
                    override fun onAnimationStart(p1: Animation) {}
                    override fun onAnimationRepeat(p1: Animation) {}

                    override fun onAnimationEnd(p1: Animation) {
                        run()
                    }
                })
                columnContainer.startAnimation(anim)
            }
        }).run()
    }

    fun setIcon(@DrawableRes iconResId: Int) {
        icons.forEach { icon ->
            ViewCompat.animate(icon)
                    .scaleX(0f)
                    .scaleY(0f)
                    .alpha(0f)
                    .setDuration(1000).withEndAction {
                        icon.setImageResource(iconResId)
                        ViewCompat.animate(icon)
                                .scaleX(1f)
                                .scaleY(1f)
                                .alpha(1f)
                                .setDuration(1000)
                                .start()
                    }.start()
        }
    }
}
```